# Blender 3.3 Normal Map bake blue and grey or transparent

Tags: normal-map

My normal map is baking transparent or blue and grey.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file (or at least a part of it) so that we can test? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: here is a link , https://www.mediafire.com/file/9jhcpvt351p34n6/dragons.blend/file

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem because it works fine for me (3.3 as well), don't forget to shade smooth the low poly: https://zupimages.net/up/22/39/4t7n.jpg

Comment: The low poly is flat shaded, which means that some rays, which are rays along the normal at that sample, miss the high poly.  In addition, your ray extrusion is set too high for the model, which will lead to different problems when you fix that; in general, a ray extrusion of 0.04 is more appropriate than the 0.2 you have, but that will miss the teeth and still possibly lead to some problems at the eye.  You might consider using a cage, but it may also be necessary to part this model out.